# Make sure that kilogram are converted to grams pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series

```
s = pd.Series({0: '1kg',
 1: '500g',
 2: '200g'})
```

What I want to do is to make a very similar column that basically has the same type of measurement, that being in grams. So in this case convert the 1kg to one thousand int value and leave the gram integer in the normal state. Note: The value can alter on the kg part. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Wanted result

```
{0:1000,
1:500,
2:200}
```

Comment: How does it generalize? Do you have other units? Only integer values? spaces?

Comment: Well in my current data from what I could see I only have kg and grams. None other, the spaces were already removed in previous treatment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module `quantiphy` handles this type of use case:

```
import pandas as pd 
from quantiphy import Quantity

s = pd.Series({0: '1kg',
 1: '500g',
 2: '200g'})

print(s.apply(Quantity))
```

Output:

```
0    1000.0
1     500.0
2     200.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Probably the cleanest and most generalisable solution. +1

Comment: @HMH1013 mine will work fine with floating point values, you just need to tweak the regex `(\d\.?\d*+)\s*(\D+)` and convert to `float` instead of `int`

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 i didn't mean for you to change your vote, Tranbi's answer is great!

Comment: I liked ur answer it teaches me what to do in similar cases.

Comment: @ mozway Thanks for the updating ! I delete the comment  now that doesn't seem like a very friendly comment.

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 well you can chose whichever, I just didn't want make it looks like I put pressure on you (I hate when people are doing it) given my response to HMH1013 comment, you're just free of your votes ;)

Comment: @HMH1013 You were partially right, thanks for commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the values/units with a short regex, then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your units and multiply:

```
units = {'kg': 1000, 'g': 1}

out = (s.str.extract('(?P<value>\d+)(?P<unit>\D+)')
        .assign(unit=lambda d: d['unit'].map(units))
        .astype(int).prod(axis=1)
      )

print(out)
```

Variant:

```
units = {'kg': 1000, 'g': 1}

df = s.str.extract('(\d+)(\D+)')

out = df[0].astype(int).mul(df[1].map(units))
```

handling floating point values and spaces:

```
units = {'kg': 1000, 'g': 1}

df = s.str.extract('(\d\.?\d*+)\s*(\D+)')

out = df[0].astype(float).mul(df[1].map(units))
```

Output:

```
0    1000
1     500
2     200
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a basic conversion function and applying it should do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series({0: '1kg',
 1: '500g',
 2: '200g'})
 
def convert(weight):
    if weight[-2:] == "kg":
        return int(weight[:-2])*1000
    elif weight[-1] == "g":
        return int(weight[:-1])
    else:
        return int(weight)

s = s.apply(convert)

print(s)
```

Output:

```py
0     1000
1     500
2     200
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the solution is using `search` method to find the string pattern and save as integer, and the fastest way to get the string complete until get the unit.

It could be done as `series`, as `array` or `dataframe` i let you the example using an array and creating a Series using it.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

s = pd.Series({0: '1kg',
 1: '500g',
 2: '200g'})

data = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    if(re.search("kg", s[i])): # Check if the elements is in kg
        c = s[i][:s[i].index("kg")] # Get all from the beginning to unit
        c = int(c)*1000 # Pass to int and pass to grames
    elif(re.search("g", s[i])): # Check if the elements is in g
        c = int(s[i][:s[i].index("g")]) # Get all from the beginning to unit and pass to int
    data.append(c) # add into the array 

s1 = pd.Series(data) # Create a series using the array with all values    
    
print(s1)
```

#### Output:

```
0    1000
1     500
2     200
dtype: int64
```